# Quantum Box and Quantum Number

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How many quantum numbers are needed to describe a stationary state of a particle in a multi-dimensional quantum box (say 73)?

Answer (score 3):

Generalizing from 1d. For every of the $d$ dimensions you have one independent momentum variable $k_i$ such that $i\in\{1..d\}$. The boundary conditions quantize them.

The *energy* on the other hand is fixed by a single positive integer, since for a free particle $$ E \propto k_1^2+k_2^2+\cdots k_d^2 \propto n_1^2+n_2^2+\cdots n^2_d\equiv n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: Of course, thanks. I didn't mean to write $n^2$ but somehow did...

Comment: I think you actually do mean to write $n^2$ there because you define the sum of all separation constants $k_i^2$ as $k^2$.  Not that it matters, it is simply a convention from solving BVPs.  Also, see my edit, you cannot say that n only ranges from $1$ to $d$ as you did before.

Comment: @MaxGraves yeah, that was a poor choice of label. I should really pay more attention to what i write today. I agree that one would normally dub the sum of the $k_i^2$ $k^2$, but i wanted to make the point that the energy is labeled by a positive integer, so ich chose $n$.

Comment: I'm being picky here but $n \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow n^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the convention is to write the sum of the integers from the separation constant as $n^2$.  I get your point though.